# Is there a numerical "missing" token to tell LSTMs to impute a missing number?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

I'm trying to impute missing spatial positions `[x, y, z]` from an object trajectory, using a bidirectional LSTM. To train, I've masked some known positions in trajectories with `mask_value = -1`, while using the unmasked trajectory as target. My intuition is this is similar to masked language modeling problems (ie. fill-in-the-missing-word, except I'm trying to fill in a missing number).

```
### Example Data ###
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'X': {0: 0.7819923262212789, 1: 0.8459722182552086, 2: -1.0, 3: 0.8694600744527876, 4: 0.854969390572484, 5: 0.801757542867478, 6: 0.741300353222318, 7: 0.8235697352260694, 8: -1.0, 9: 0.7546104557615212, 10: 0.7499357344834469, 11: 0.7829158454961754}, 
                         'Y': {0: 0.8626673097793318, 1: 0.8375979741951041, 2: -1.0, 3: 0.7829012420113346, 4: 0.8166525985771135, 5: 0.8517183166525982, 6: 0.8004341010490774, 7: 0.8551790666827446, 8: -1.0, 9: 0.823200289400699, 10: 0.8178704931870248, 11: 0.8507657060171225}, 
                         'Z': {0: 0.5208070617906684, 1: 0.4317360235393022, 2: -1.0, 3: 0.5188734762505255, 4: 0.5005464480874317, 5: 0.5905842791088692, 6: 0.4405632618747371, 7: 0.405380411937789, 8: -1.0, 9: 0.5386717108028583, 10: 0.4439680538041194, 11: 0.4710382513661201}})

df_target = pd.DataFrame({'X': {0: 0.7819923262212789, 1: 0.8459722182552086, 2: 0.8341664048441855, 3: 0.8694600744527876, 4: 0.854969390572484, 5: 0.801757542867478, 6: 0.741300353222318, 7: 0.8235697352260694, 8: 0.8037283520417406, 9: 0.7546104557615212, 10: 0.7499357344834469, 11: 0.7829158454961754}, 
                          'Y': {0: 0.8626673097793318, 1: 0.8375979741951041, 2: 0.8172555167008316, 3: 0.7829012420113346, 4: 0.8166525985771135, 5: 0.8517183166525982, 6: 0.8004341010490774, 7: 0.8551790666827446, 8: 0.8476546484987337, 9: 0.823200289400699, 10: 0.8178704931870248, 11: 0.8507657060171225}, 
                          'Z': {0: 0.5208070617906684, 1: 0.4317360235393022, 2: 0.4711223203026479, 3: 0.5188734762505255, 4: 0.5005464480874317, 5: 0.5905842791088692, 6: 0.4405632618747371, 7: 0.405380411937789, 8: 0.4345102984447247, 9: 0.5386717108028583, 10: 0.4439680538041194, 11: 0.4710382513661201}})
```

What I've found is the LSTM doesn't seem to "focus" attention on the masked values, and also does not seem to learn to "copy over" values when the input is unmasked. Is there a type of **"missing token" for numerical data** that can specify which value to predict?

```
### Example Model ###
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as K

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

# define model
n_timesteps = 12
batch_size = 1
mask_value = -1
ndim_per_time_input = 3 # only 3 readout per input (x, y, z)
ndim_per_time_output = 3 # only 3 readout per output (x, y, z)

# reformat input
X = df_input.values
Y = df_target.values
X = X.reshape(1, n_timesteps, ndim_per_time_input)
Y = Y.reshape(1, n_timesteps, ndim_per_time_output)

#### define LSTM ####
model = Sequential()

## masking layer
input_shape = (n_timesteps, ndim_per_time_input)

## input layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, 
                             return_sequences = True,
                             dropout = 0.2), input_shape=input_shape, merge_mode='ave'))

## output layer
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(ndim_per_time_output, activation = 'linear')))

## loss function
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam') 

# train LSTM
for epoch in range(1000):
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 1, batch_size = batch_size, verbose=2)
```

Comment: first check that the model does not erase negative values with RELU for example. Second, think about what your desired output is. I would try to have an output unmasked means the LSTM must guess missing numbers, that means one to one in/out over a sequence and this MUST work. You may explain in your question how to do manage sequence and what output you want to have